# No module named PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qgis

i tried compile my qgis plugin and i have this output.

```
C:\Users\Mateusz\.qgis2\python\plugins\Selector>pyuic4 -o selector_dialog_base.p
y selector_dialog_base.ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 31, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Im using python27 (x64).
PyQt4-4.11.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.6-x64

I set all env path like PYTHONPATH and PATH to my PyQt. You can even see this path in output where file `pyuic.py` is in my PyQt4 package. Have u any ideas what i can do ?

I also re-installed PyQt twice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the OSGEO4W Shell (if you install the Osgeo4w package, the icon is on desktop) and then launch your pyuic4 command from there.